# Database - Password protection

Tags: java, mysql, sql

i have a registration form, when i save that to my database i can see my password in cleartext is there any way to replace that with asterisk or circles so that no one will be able to read .
i dont want any encryption just simple replacement by asterisk

[image]

Comment: `i dont want any encryption just simple replacement by asterisk` **No**.  Do *not* do this.  Don't be lazy, use encryption.  You are doing your uses a great disservice by not encrypting their passwords.

Comment: Better yet, salt and hash your passwords. This is a broad topic, and there is a ton of stuff out there.

Comment: i tried alot using md5 and sha1 but nothing is working right for me

Comment: @yshavit yes sir its dummy data this time

Comment: is there any simple way to use * instead of cleardata

Comment: This is so much of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) we might have to redefine it...  You can't get hashing/encryption to work (the X) so you store it clear text, now you want to try to obfuscate it in the database (the Y).  Fix the problem.  Use encryption.  If you have a specific question on how to implement it, please make a new question and we'll be glad to help.  But I cannot in good conscience help you do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Siyual sir can ii mail u the file so that u cn have a look whtr its possible to hash it or not

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, a password should always be encrypted so that its true value can never be established (as far as I'm concerned, this should be law). Not even administrators, developers, whatever, should be able to establish the true value of the password. It is the encryption that is compared to another encryption that determines the correct password. A couple real good ***password*** encryption mechanisms are **BCrypt** (or **jBCrypt**) and **Argon2** (or **Argon2i**). **PBKDF2** is pretty good too but not as secure as the previously mentioned, at least from what I've read about it.

Let's do an example using jBCrypt encryption along with a SQLite database which we'll create:

First you need to [download the jBCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/#download) source file and create the jBCrypt Library (this is actually BCrypt with a little simplicity coded into it):

Create a new Library project within your favorite Java IDE and name it **jBCrypt**;
Add a new package to your jBCrypt project named **org.mindrot.jbcrypt**;
To your package, add a new JAva Class and name it **BCrypt**;
Copy/paste the source code into your new class (under the **package org.mindrot.jbcrypt;** line);
Build the JAR file;
Copy/paste te built jar file to a location where you keep all your Java Libraries;

Now you will need to download the [SQLite JDBC Driver](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads/sqlite-jdbc-3.16.1.jar) so that we can create and access a SQLite database. I believe the newest version is ***sqlite-jdbc-3.16.1.jar***. Store this JAR file where you keep all your Java Libraries.

Next you need to create a new **Java Application** within your favorite Java IDE, name it: **Login**. Add the BCrypt jar and SQLite Driver jar to your project then copy/paste the following runnable code into it:

```
package login;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt;
import static org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt.hashpw;

/**
 *
 * @author DevilsHnd
 */
public class Login {
    // Create a dummy JFrame. This is done so that
    // the Dialog boxes that are used in the application
    // do not hide behind the IDE. Not a problem for
    // some.
    private static final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    // Define the BCrypt workload to use when generating
    // password hashes. 10-31 is a valid value.
    private static final int workload = 12;

    /**
     * A simple test case for the main method, verify that a pre-generated test
     * hash verifies successfully for the password it represents, and also
     * generate a new hash and ensure that the new hash verifies just the same.
     * @param args
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedAssignment")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Set Appplication Look&Feel
        setLookAndFeel();

        // Build an small example SQLite database.
        if (!buildSQLiteDatabase("ApplicationDatabase", "Users")) {
            System.out.println("Can't build SQLite database!");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        // Set a loop so you can play with this for a
        // while with differnt User Names and Passwords.
        while (true) {
            String uName = "";
            String passWrd = "";
            // Get User input as to User Name and Password.
            // using a custom Input Dialog...
            // Build the dialog Panel...
            BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);
            JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>Please supply the specified Login information<br>"
                                + "to add a new User and Password to the database<br>"
                                + "or select the User Name you want to test the<br>"
                                + "Password for:<br><br>");
            panel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5,5));
            JPanel labels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,2,2));
            labels.add(new JLabel("User Name:", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
            labels.add(new JLabel("Password:", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
            p.add(labels, BorderLayout.WEST);
            JPanel controls = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,2,2));

            String[] choices = fillComboFromDB("ApplicationDatabase", "Users");
            JComboBox userName = new JComboBox(choices);
            userName.setEditable(true);
            userName.setSelectedItem("");

            //JTextField userName = new JTextField();
            controls.add(userName);
            JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField();
            controls.add(password);
            p.add(controls, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            panel.add(p);
            JLabel baseLabel = new JLabel("<html><pre><font size=2>                  "
                    + "Select <font color=red>Cancel</font> to quit</font></pre></html>");
            panel.add(baseLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            // Get Input from User...
            int res = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, panel, "User Login ...",
                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

            // Process the result from our custom Input Dialog
            boolean itemIsSelected = false;
            if (res == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION && !userName.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("") &&
                    !Arrays.toString(password.getPassword()).equals("")) {
                if (userName.getSelectedIndex() != -1) { itemIsSelected = true; }
                uName = userName.getSelectedItem().toString();
                char[] pass = password.getPassword();
                for (int i = 0; i < pass.length; i++) {
                    passWrd+= Character.toString(pass[i]);
                }
            }
            else {
                //dialog was canceled...exit loop
                break;
            }

            if (!itemIsSelected) {
                //Encrypt the supplied Password for the supplied User.
                String salt = BCrypt.gensalt(workload);
                String encryptedPassword = hashpw(passWrd, salt);

                // Save User Name and Password into database
                if (!storeUserPass("ApplicationDatabase", "Users", uName, encryptedPassword)) {
                    System.out.println("Can Not Store User Data Into Database!");
                    continue;
                }

                // Inform of database entry
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"The supplied User Name and encrypted "
                        + "Password has\nbeen stored into database!", "User Saved To "
                        + "Database.\n\nEcrypted Password is:\n" + encryptedPassword,
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        continue;
            }

            // Get User Name and Password from database...
            String storedPassword = getPasswordFromDB("ApplicationDatabase", "Users", uName);
            // Is it a valid hash?
            if (!storedPassword.startsWith("$2a$")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"The encrypted password stored in database does not\n"
                        + "appear to contain a valid hash!", "Invalid Password Hash!",
                        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Stored Password is: " + storedPassword);

            // Compare the supplied password with what is in
            // the database for supplied User...
            if (hashpw(passWrd, storedPassword).equals(storedPassword)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Your Password Is VALID! You're Good To Go!",
                        "Valid Password!",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"The Password Supplied Is INVALID!",
                        "Valid Password!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

            // Try another entry?
            res = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame,"Do you want to try another User Name or\n"
                    + "Change the password of a current User in DB?",
                      "Try Another User?",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            if (res == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) { break; }
        }
        System.exit(0); // Close application
    }

    /**
     * This method can be used to generate a string representing an account
     * password suitable for storing in a database. It will be an OpenBSD-style
     * crypt(3) formatted hash string of length=60 The bcrypt workload is
     * specified in the above static variable, a value from 10 to 31. A workload
     * of 12 is a very reasonably safe default. This automatically handles secure
     * 128-bit salt generation and storage within the hash.
     *
     * @param password_plaintext The account's plaintext password as provided
     * during account creation, or when changing an account's password.
     *
     * @return String - a string of length 60 that is the bcrypt hashed password
     * in crypt(3) format.
     */
    /*
    public static String hashPassword(String password_plaintext) {
        String salt = BCrypt.gensalt(workload);
        String hashed_password = hashpw(password_plaintext, salt);
        return (hashed_password);
    }
    */

    /**
     * This method can be used to verify a computed hash from a plaintext (e.g.
     * during a login request) with that of a stored hash from a database. The
     * password hash from the database must be passed as the second variable.
     *
     * @param passwordAsPlainText The accounts plaintext password, as provided
     * during a login request
     *
     * @param storedEncryption The accounts stored password hash, retrieved from the
     * authorization database
     *
     * @return boolean - true if the password matches the password of the stored
     * hash, false otherwise
     */
    /*
    public static boolean checkPassword(String passwordAsPlainText, String storedEncryption) {
        boolean password_verification;

        if (null == storedEncryption || !storedEncryption.startsWith("$2a$")) {
            throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Invalid encryption provided for comparison");
        }

        password_verification = checkpw(passwordAsPlainText, storedEncryption);

        return (password_verification);
    }
    */

    /**
     * This will build a SQLite database (only if it doesn't already exist) named
     * ApplicationDatabase.sqlite. It also builds a database Table name Users which
     * consists of a ID column (Integer - Auto increment - Primary Key), UserName
     * column (Text - Null not allowed), and a Password column (Text - Null not
     * Allowed).
     *
     * @param databaseName (String) The database name to use. If the .sqlite file
     * extention is not supplied with the name then it is automatically appended.
     *
     * @param tableName (String) The Table name to create.
     *
     * @return (Boolean) True if successful and false if not.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public static boolean buildSQLiteDatabase(String databaseName, String tableName) {
        if (!databaseName.endsWith("sqlite")) { databaseName+= ".sqlite"; }

        //Skip building DB if it already Exists.
        File file = new File(databaseName);
        if (file.exists()) { return true; }

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            String url = "jdbc:sqlite:" + databaseName;
            //create the DB
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

            // Create the table in DB..
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName + " ("
                    + "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"
                    + "UserName TEXT NOT NULL,"
                    + "Password TEXT NOT NULL);";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            return true;
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        finally {
            try { if (conn != null) { stmt.close(); conn.close(); } }
            catch (SQLException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }

    public static String[] fillComboFromDB(String databaseName, String tableName) {
        if (!databaseName.endsWith("sqlite")) { databaseName+= ".sqlite"; }
        String sql;

        Connection conn;
        PreparedStatement stmt;

        int count = 0;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            String url = "jdbc:sqlite:" + databaseName;
            //create the DB
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

            // See if User Name already exists in database.
            // If it does then use the sql UPDATE statement
            // instead of the INSERT INTO statement.
            sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS rCount FROM " + tableName +";";
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                while (rs.next()) { count = rs.getInt("rCount"); }
            }
            String[] returnItems =  new String[count];
            sql = "SELECT UserName FROM " + tableName +";";
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                count = 0;
                while (rs.next()) {
                    returnItems[count] = rs.getString("UserName");
                    count++;
                }
                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
            }
            conn.close();
            return returnItems;
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This will either: <pre>
     *
     *      - Create a new record within the supplied table if the supplied User
     *        Name does not exist or;
     *
     *      - It will Update the record (password in particular) for a User that
     *        already exists within the database table. This is based on the User
     *        Name supplied.
     * </pre>
     *
     * @param databaseName (String) The database name to use. If the .sqlite file
     * extention is not supplied with the name then it is automatically appended.
     *
     * @param tableName (String) The Table name to access.
     *
     * @param name (String) User Name to either store or modify password for.
     *
     * @param pass (String) The Password to store.
     *
     * @return (Boolean) True if successful and false if not.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public static boolean storeUserPass(String databaseName, String tableName,
                    String name, String pass) {
        if (!databaseName.endsWith("sqlite")) { databaseName+= ".sqlite"; }
        String sql;

        Connection conn;
        PreparedStatement stmt;

        int count = 0;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            String url = "jdbc:sqlite:" + databaseName;
            //create the DB
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

            // See if User Name already exists in database.
            // If it does then use the sql UPDATE statement
            // instead of the INSERT INTO statement.
            sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS rCount FROM " + tableName +
                    " WHERE UserName = '" + name + "';";
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                while (rs.next()) { count = rs.getInt("rCount"); }
                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
            }

            if (count > 0) {
                sql = "UPDATE " + tableName + " SET Password = '" + pass +
                        "' WHERE UserName = '" + name + "';";
            }
            else {
                sql = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + "(UserName, Password) "
                   + "VALUES ('" + name + "','"+ pass + "');";
            }
            try (
                //Modify data in table or insert data into table
                Statement smt = conn.createStatement()) {
                smt.execute(sql);
                smt.close();
            }
            conn.close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This will retrieve the encrypted password from database for the supplied
     * User Name.
     *
     * @param databaseName (String) The database name to use. If the .sqlite file
     * extention is not supplied with the name then it is automatically appended.
     *
     * @param tableName (String) The Table name to access.
     *
     * @param userName (String) User Name to retrieve password for.
     *
     * @return (String) the Encrypted password.
     */
    public static String getPasswordFromDB(String databaseName,
                            String tableName, String userName) {
        if (!databaseName.endsWith("sqlite")) { databaseName+= ".sqlite"; }
        String sql = "SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE UserName = '" + userName + "';";
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            String url = "jdbc:sqlite:" + databaseName;
            //create the DB
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

            String p;
            try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                p = "";
                while (rs.next()) {
                    p = rs.getString("Password");
                }
            }
            conn.close();
            return p;
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
        finally {
            try { if (conn != null) { conn.close(); } }
            catch (SQLException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }

    //Set the application's Look & Feel.
    private static void setLookAndFeel() {
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                //Nimbus
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```